Understanding Contradictory Autocorrelation Findings in Residual Analysis
Question
I came across an answer regarding how to evaluate the autocorrelation of residuals.
However, when I apply two different approaches, the Durbin-Watson test (Fig. 1) and creating time-lagged residuals (Fig. 2), I obtain conflicting results regarding autocorrelation. One method identifies autocorrelation, while the other does not. As a result, I'm seeking clarification on this discrepancy.
Can anyone please help shed light on this?
Fig 1.

Fig 2.

